# how to fix the promise pending in cucumber NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber

I'm writing cucumber test and expecting the value `true` from this function **getOutout** and doing the assert with the return value but I'm getting the below error:

**Error Message:**

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: undefined == true
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  generatedMessage: true,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: undefined,
  expected: true,
  operator: '==',
  [Symbol(originalCallSite)]: [ CallSite {}, CallSite {} ],
  [Symbol(mutatedCallSite)]: [ CallSite {}, CallSite {} ]
```

**step.js**

```
const { Given, When, Then } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const assert = require('assert');


let isSuccess;
Then('validate the {string} product', function (productType) {

  var params = {
    stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-west-1:121:stateMachine:test',
    maxResults: '25',
    nextToken: null,
    statusFilter: 'SUCCEEDED'
  };

  const result = getOutout(params).then(function() {
     assert.equal(result, true);
    })
  
});


async function getOutout(params) {

  const stepfunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
  });

  try {
    isSuccess = await listExecute(params, stepfunctions);
    console.log(isSuccess, 'Output') 
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

const listExecute = function (params, stepfunctions) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stepfunctions.listExecutions(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else
        data.executions.forEach(function (result) {
          let params = {
            executionArn: result.executionArn
          };
          stepfunctions.describeExecution(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else {
              resolve(true)
            }
          });

        });
    });
  })
}
```

Any help would be much appreciate to fix the issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you did this, but it is bad asynchronous code

```
const result = getOutout(params).then(function() {
  })
assert.equal(result, true);
```

you need to put the assert within the promise callback:

```
getOutout(params).then(function(result) {
  assert.equal(result, true);
})
```

Comment: My bad, I updated the code but I'm getting 'undefined' for value result instead of 'true' - post is updated with latest one. How to use promise callback here - sorry I'm new to java scripting. Thanks!

Comment: it's giving you `undefined` because `result` is not defined in the scope of `getOutout`. Also, for your test case to work you need to return `isSuccess` from `getOutout`. @DaveBrady